# JavaFX - when are widthProperty() and heightProperty() set / updated

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop application where users can drop new 'components' onto a canvas and then drag them around. This is the code I'm using to achieve this:

**In CanvasController class**

```
canvas.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(DragEvent event) {

    // Create new component
    ComponentController component = new ComponentController();

    // Add the component to the canvas
    canvas.getChildren().add(component);

    // Relocate the component to the mouse location
    component.relocateToPointInScene(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(),event.getSceneY()));

    // Make the component visible
    component.setVisible(true);

    // Set drop complete
    event.setDropCompleted(true);

    // Consume event
    event.consume();

  }
}
```

**In ComponentController class**

```
protected final void relocateToPointInScene(Point2D scenePoint) {

  // Create a point in the parent (canvas) copordinates
  Point2D parentPoint = getParent().sceneToLocal(scenePoint);

  // Locate the node so that its centre is located at the parent point
  this.relocate((int) (parentPoint.getX() - (widthProperty().getValue()/2.0)), (int) (parentPoint.getY() - heightProperty().getValue()/2.0));

}
```

Functionally it works fine, but the new component isn't being placed at the correct point on the canvas - it should be located so that the centre of the component is at the mouse location but instead it is dropped so that the top left corner is at the mouse location.

I've worked out that this is because the values of the widthProperty() and heightProperty() of the new component are still zero when `relocateToPointInScene(Point2D scenePoint)` is called. If I pick the component back up, drag it and drop it again the code works as expected, because now the widthProperty() and heightProperty() are non-zero.

```
canvas.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(DragEvent event) {

    // Relocate the component to the mouse location
    component.relocateToPointInScene(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(),event.getSceneY()));

  }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Why are the widthProperty() and heightProperty() still zero when called in the drop function? - At this point the object has been constructed, initialised and added to the parent (canvas) so I don't see why these values shouldn't be set.
2. What is happening between the first and second calls to `relocateToPointInScene(Point2D scenePoint)` to change these values.

Comment: The values won't be non-zero until a layout pass occurs, which happens lazily. You can potentially force a layout by invoking [`Parent#layout()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layout()) on the parent.

Comment: You'll probably need to invoke [`Node#applyCss()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss()) as well (method documentation gives an example).

Comment: Yep that solves it, thanks! Calling canvas.applyCss() followed by canvas.layout(), after adding the component as a child, but before relocating it does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Slaw suggested, calling `canvas.applyCss()` followed by `canvas.layout()`, after adding the component as a child, but before relocating it does the trick.